# Cleaning up java code, multiple else if statements

Tags: java, coding-style

This method filter frame score and add it. Already improved what I could, but it seems to me that it is possible to improve even more, but how I don’t know.  Any ideas?

```
 public boolean addFramePinsDown(int player, Frame frame) {
   
    if (game.getPlayersList().size() > player) {
        if (game.getPlayersList().get(player).getFrame() < BowlingEnum.MAX_FRAMES.getValue()) {
            if (frame.getThirdRoll() == 0) {
                if (frame.getFirstRoll() + frame.getSecondRoll() <= BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue()) {
                    addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else if (game.getPlayersList().get(player).getFrame() == BowlingEnum.MAX_FRAMES.getValue()) {
            if (frame.getFirstRoll() == 10) {
                if (frame.getSecondRoll() == 10 && frame.getThirdRoll() <= BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue()) {
                    addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                    return true;
                } else if (frame.getSecondRoll() < BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue() && frame.getThirdRoll() == 0) {
                    addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (frame.getSecondRoll() == BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue() &&
                    frame.getThirdRoll() <= BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue()) {
                addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                return true;
            } else if(frame.getFirstRoll() + frame.getSecondRoll() == BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue() &&
                    frame.getThirdRoll() <= BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue()){
                addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                return true;
            } else if (frame.getFirstRoll() + frame.getSecondRoll() < BowlingEnum.MAX_PINS.getValue() &&
                    frame.getThirdRoll() == 0) {
                addAndCountFrames(player, frame);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `switch` statements?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. You think this will shorten the code?

Comment: Why not use early returns? You don't need `else`  after using return, see for example https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need now is abstracting large if branches into a method.

If you use Intellij IDEA, you can select some code and [extract method](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-method.html) which will automatically create a method with the right parameters.

Then, you give that method a descriptive name such that someone can just look at the method call and figure out what that method will do.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern [Specification](https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) from the Martin Fowler's blog could help you.

In addition, I think you should read the first 100 pages of [Clean code](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code) from Robert C. Martin.

It will explain all you have to know to made a more lisible code.